# Explicitly say which conditions to fold Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editor, code-folding, sqr

I have a custom language for SQR and I'm trying to get the code folding feature to work for Notepad++. In SQR, the case of the keywords do not matter.

`Begin-Procedure` is the same as `bEgIn-ProCEdure`. The same goes for the traditional `if ... end-if` is the same as `If ... End-If`.

In notepad++ you can specify a code folding feature to fold the code. My problem is that I only want to specify the code to fold on `if ... end-if` regardless of case. Notepad++ currently tries to fold code everywhere it sees `if`.

Meaning, if I name a procedure with `Begin-Procedure Verify-Something`, the `if` in *ver**if**y* attempts to get folded leaving me with undesirable results.

How can I specifically specify I only want to fold code on the single instances of `if` and not wherever `if` is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "Folding in code 2 style (separators needed)" and make sure you have a check in "Ignore case". Also, if you have "-" in the "Operators & Delimiters" tab, make sure it's only in the "Operators 2 (separators required)" section.

[image: Ignore case checked]

[image: Folding in code 2 style (separators needed)]

[image: Example code]]